# Cordova mobile accessibility plugin breaks the whole app

Tags: cordova, mobile, accessibility, phonegap

I'm developing an application using Cordova 7.0.1, I need to use the phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility plugin for ignoring the device font-size but when I install the plugin it breaks everything for something related to the cordova-plugin-network-information I'm using.
When I start the app it freeze on the splash image and the console give me this error:

> Uncaught module cordova-plugin-network-information.network not found

I tried to unistall the network information plugin and let the accessibility plugin to install it (it's a dependency) but nothing changed. 
The "cordova plugin list" shows me the network plugin installed

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, apparently I was using an old version of the Netowrk Information plugin with a different package name (org.apache.cordova.network-information), updating it some files didn't change the package name with the new one and gave me errors. I manually changed all the occurrences with the new package name and now everything works!